# Write the trigonometric expression as an algebraic expression

Tags: trigonometry

Write the trigonometric expression as an algebraic expression.

$6 \cos(2 \cos^{-1} x)$

Can someone explain to me how to do this? I tried it on my own after watching a youtube video from patrickjmt but it's confusing.

My work:

[image]

Comment: Hint: $\cos(2a)=2\cos^2 a-1$.

Comment: I don't get it still

Comment: You have by now been given quite complete answers. Your $\cos\theta=2x$ is not right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have: $6\cos (2\cos^{-1}x) = 6(2\cos^2(\cos^{-1}x)-1)=6(2x^2-1)$

Comment: How did you get from the first one to the second one?

Comment: $\cos(2\theta) = 2\cos^2\theta - 1, \theta = \cos^{-1}x$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

use:
$$
\cos 2 \alpha= \cos^2 \alpha-\sin^2 \alpha= 2\cos^2 \alpha-1
$$
for $\alpha=\cos^{-1} x$. Than note that , by definition, $\cos (\cos^{-1} x)=x$

So you find:
$$
\cos (2 \cos^{-1} x)=2\cos^2(\cos^{-1} x)-1=2x^2-1
$$

Answer (score 0):

This is $\cos\Big(2\times\text{something}\Big)$.  There's a standard identity for that:
\begin{align}
\cos\Big(2\times\text{something}\Big) & = \cos^2\Big(\text{something}\Big) - \sin^2\Big(\text{something}\Big) \\[10pt]
& = \Big(\cos(\text{something})\Big)^2 - \Big(\sin^2(\text{something})\Big)^2
\end{align}
Then you need to deal with $\cos(\arccos(x))$ (that part is easy) and $\sin(\arccos(x))$.  The latter can be done via a diagram like the one you've drawn.